# Git grep url regex

Tags: git, bash, git-grep

I am trying to create bash script that checks my source code to flag absolutely url's as all of our devs should be using relative url's when it comes to internal links.

I was thinking to create a bash script that could then be included as part of our pre-commit hooks, so using git grep also seemed logical.  I have everything working, however, I'm having some difficulty with the regex for the git grep.

Here is what I have so far:

```
`# Set's the regex test & files
 readonly FORBIDDEN_RE="\((\|'\|\"\)\(http\|https\):\/\/\(www\.\)\?example\.com"
 readonly FORBIDDEN_FILES="'*.md' '*.html' ':!README.md'"

 # Adds double quotes around regex since without them git grep doesn't work, 
 # However, even trying to put the re_test variable in place of FORBIDDEN_RE
 # is not working in the actual git grep.
 # re_test="\"""$FORBIDDEN_RE""\""

if [ "$(git grep -n --cached -i -e "$FORBIDDEN_RE" -- "$FORBIDDEN_FILES")" != 0 ]; then
  git grep -n --cached -i -e "$FORBIDDEN_RE" -- "$FORBIDDEN_FILES"
  echo "ERROR: You're trying to make a commit that contains a hardcoded internal URL. Please make it relative."
  exit 1
fi`
```

And here are the tests that I'm doing and if I expect them to be flagged by the regex or not:

`http://www.example.com` - not flagged

`(http://www.example.com` - flagged (We use markdown, so this would be the link in a markdown file)

`"http://www.example.com` - flagged (because this the double quote signifies this is probably in an href value)

`'http://www.example.com` - flagged (because this could also signify the URL is in an href value)

`http://example.com` - not flagged

`(http://example.com` - flagged

`"http://example.com` - flagged

`'http://example.com` - flagged

`(http://example.com?param=abc` - flagged

`"http://example.com?param=abc` - flagged

`'http://example.com?param=abc` - flagged

`(http://subdomain.example.com` - not flagged

What works for me ***perfectly*** just using the command line is:
`git grep -n --cached -i -e "\((\|'\|\"\)\(http\|https\):\/\/\(www\.\)\?example\.com" -- '*.html' '*.md' ':!README.md'`

However, with all the character escaping that I'm having to do and trying to get quotes around the regex when doing it in a bash file, I just can't seem to get this working within the bash file.

I echo'd out what `$FORBIDDEN_RE`'s value is and it seems to be taking out the `\"` in the first capture group that is looking for either "(", single quote, or double quote.  Here is the value of `$FORBIDDEN_RE` when I echo out:
`git grep -n --cached -i -e "\((\|'\|"\)\(http\|https\):\/\/\(www\.\)\?example\.com" -- '*.md' '*.html' ':!README.md'`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or maybe how to make the regex simpler to work with git grep?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this script works at all since you have single quoted globs inside a variable that you expand in double quotes when passing to git so it sees a *single* file argument of `'*.md' '*.html' ':!README.md'`. Are you sure that script finds anything at all? Add `set -x` to the script to see what the shell is **actually** running and don't trust `echo` for things like this.

Comment: You can also save yourself huge headaches here (and likely avoid your problems) by givin multiple `-e` patterns to `git grep` since it handles them as `or` that way (by default).